# I Want To Do A Searching By Keywords And Get All Sold Products By Range Of Dates

Tags: c#, ebay-api

I am adding a searching in my application. and I want to get a list of all sold products and calculate a n average by price.

for example:

I could write:

keywords: Iphone 7 initial date: 2017/08/01 final date: 201/08/13

I want to get all sold products count with Iphone 7 between the two dates.

Answer (score 0):

At the simplest implementation, you'll need
1. Parsing logic - something to put the string into an object you can use
   From: keywords: Iphone 7 initial date: 2017/08/01 final date: 201/08/13

to:

```
// this is an example
public class SearchCriteria
{
   public string Keyword {get;set;}
   public string From {get;set;}
   public string To {get;set;}
}

public class Parser
{

   public SearchCriteria Parse(string searchExpression)
   {
       var keyword = string.Empty;
       var from = DateTime.Min;
       var to = DateTime.Max;
       // To do
       // ... parse your string here
       //
       return new SearchCriteria(){Keyword = keyword, From = from, To = to};
   }

}
```

2. Object to query conversion and execution. You have a ton of possible choices here, ADO, Linq, EF, ORMs, Micro-ORMs.... anything that can return you a recordset/collection

```
public class ProductsAndAveragePrice
{
    public List<Products> Products {get;set;}
    public decimal AveragePrice {get;set;}
}

 public ProductsAndAveragePrice GetProducts(SearchCriteria criteria)
 {
      // pretend SQL String Based repo
      var sb = new StringBuilder();
      sb.AppendLine("SELECT ProductName, Price ");
      sb.AppendLine("FROM MyProductsTable");
      sb.AppendLine("WHERE Keyword = @keyword");
      sb.AppendLine("AND From >= @from");
      sb.AppendLine("AND To <= @to");

      // To do
      // ...supply the parameters and execute the query

      var products = new List<Product>();
      foreach(var row in rows)
      {
           products.Add(new Product() {Name = row["ProductName"], Price = row["Price"]};
      }

      return new ProductsAndAveragePrice(){
                 Products = products,
                 Price = products.Select(m => m.Price).Ave();
             };
 }
```

You get the drift.

Comment: I am talking about ebay API

Comment: Any idea to get sold count of research results

Comment: How to get sold item count after conducted findItemsByKeywords.

Thanks